# After calling trigger on a browser event, how can I call a function when it has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling trigger on a checkbox to flip its state. Once this is done I need to call a function. Part of the function counts the number of boxes checked so this function can only be called after the checkbox has flipped.

```
 $('input',this).trigger('click');

 // What do I do to call afterTrigger() when 'input' click event has finished.

 function afterTrigger(){
     // ... calculation
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function directly after the trigger event.

```
$('input',this).trigger('click'); 
afterTriger();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was getting intermittent results. Thought this must be it. I'll have to keep digging.

Answer (score 1):

Calls to `.trigger('foo')` are synchronous, so you can just call your function.

```
$(this).find('input').trigger('click');
afterTrigger();
```